# Sails service returns MongoDb results when no Waterline associations exist but then fails when they DO exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm building a sails.js api with MongoDb as my db.

Those are my models (simplified just for the sake of this question):

`models/Passport.js` simplified:

```
identifier: {
      type: 'string'
 },

owner: {
      model: 'User',
      required: true
 },
```

`models/User.js` simplified:

```
username: {
        type: 'string',
        unique: true
 },
passports: {
        collection: 'Passport',
        via: 'owner'
}
```

***The problem***

In a sails.js service `login` function I first try to get the user by a username from the `User` collection.

```
sails.models.user.findOne({username: 'demo'}).exec(function onExec(error, user)      {
    user; //contains user info
}
```

**So far so good.**

Then when the user is fetched (which is successfull), I grab his user.id and try to fetch his passport from the Passport collection.

```
sails.models.passport.findOne({owner:user.id}).exec(function onExec(error, passp) {
    if(passp==undefined)    //puppies dying in this line!!!!
        throw new Error('Can't find this passport');
    }
}
```

The returned `passp` object is undefined.
**What... WHY?**

**Additional info:**

Running `> db.passport.find({owner:"theCorrectUserId"})` in my mongo shell DOES return the correct passport thus its not a matter of an incorrect id, and also, running :

```
sails.models.passport.find().exec(function onExec(error, passports) {
    passports; //does contain all my passports
}
```

does contain all my passports. Thus its not a programming error either!

**Aha moment:**

What I've found over hours of banging my head on the wall is that ***removing the association*** and thus making my models like so:

`models/Passport.js` simplified:

```
identifier: {
      type: 'string'
 },

owner: {
      type: 'string'
      required: true
 }
```

`models/User.js` simplified:

```
username: {
        type: 'string',
        unique: true
 }
```

does solve the problem, and makes my `passp` object fetch the correct data..

Am I using Waterline associations wrong? But then why does it work in mongo shell when the association exists?

Do I even need associations since I'm using 2 different queries in my service? What about performance?

Comment: No more logos/images thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use the first models architecture.

This is how you should do it with Waterline:

```
sails.models.user
    .findOne({ username: username })
    // The populate method allows you to get associated data
    .populate('passports') 
    .exec(function (err, user) {
        // Handle errors
        if(err) return next('An unknown error has occured');
        if(!user) return next('Can\'t find this user');

        if(!user.passports || !user.passports.length)
            return next('This user has no passports');

        // The User has at least one passport
        ...

        return next(null, user);
}
```

The `next` method takes you back to your controller. Here is how you should use your service:

```
sails.services.myService
    .login(username, password, function (err, user) {
         ...
});
```

As you can see, there is only one query left :-).

Here is the docs about [associations with the Sails ORM](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations).

Comment: Thanks this did work. Quick question, is this better than running 2 queries performance wise?

Comment: I've never heard of such benchmarks... But it's absolutely the case for relational databases like MySQL.

Comment: Maybe could you try to test both methods lots of time and record how much it took for your particular case?

Comment: Also another problem I have with this particular solution is this: the `user.passports[0]` object is no longer of type models/Passport.js. Its a plain object. And from what I know theres NO typecasting in javascript. That is a problem for me, and thus I must return back on running 2 queries!

Comment: I think you should open a new question. It could be interesting for a lot of people, including me :-).

Comment: Ok, new question opened here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526939/waterline-mongodb-populated-fetched-object-looses-its-type-and-prototype-funct

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing:

```
sails.models.passport.findOne({owner:user.id})
```

try:

```
sails.models.passport.findOne({owner:user})
```